# initializing a vtkSmartPointer with own inherited class

Tags: c++, constructor, smart-pointers, vtk

I inherited a class from a vtk class. The constructor of that class needs to get two arguments passed.  How do I have to use the New() operator?

Thanks

Here is an example:

```
class MyClass:vtkClass
{
MyClass(argument1, argument2);

static MyClass* New()
}
```

and the initialization

```
vtkSmartPointer<MyClass> class = vtkSmartPointer<MyClass(??)>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following mail list posting means you can not get around the requirement to constructor with 0 arguments:

http://www.vtk.org/pipermail/vtkusers/2012-July/124922.html

As a result you will have to make the constructor of your class take 0 arguments. Then Initialize like this:

```
vtkSmartPointer<MyClass> class = vtkSmartPointer<MyClass>::New();
```

The implementation of Myclass::New() should either use vtkStandardNewMacro or you can just implement it as

```
MyClass *
MyClass::New()
{
    return new MyClass();
}
```

After the you have the class instance use an Initialize(argument1,argument2) function to init your class variables instead of inside the constructor.